# Run shell script from another shell script and make all the relative paths accessible

Tags: java, shell, unix, path

I am trying to call a shell script2 from another shell script1, where script2 is running a java command like -

```
java -jar target/dataMigratio-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

the jar access a file named data.txt to work on it. below is the directory structure -

```
|-script1
|-javafolder
  |- target
          |-dataMigratio-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar 
  |- data.txt
  |- script2
```

while content of script1 - 
`./javafolder/script2.sh`

content of script2 - 
`java -jar target/dataMigratio-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`

running 
`./script1` is giving the below error

> java.io.FileNotFoundException: data.txt

I don't want to hardcode the path of data.txt and want to keep in the directory same as script2.

Any help appreciated. Thanks !

Comment: For a bash-specific solution, putting `DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"` in the script gives the current dir of the script. Then you can reference other files relative to that.

Comment: boot-and-bonnet  providing String `javafolder`  to `dirname` placeholder didn't helped though :(

Comment: No need to substitute anything, `dirname` is the actual command. `$DIR/data.txt` can then be used to reference the data file.

Comment: actually accessing the data file code is in the java but yes this helps in some way to access the jar file atleast. thanks !

Comment: You could pass the data file path as an argument when executing the jar, or `cd` to `$DIR` for execution, and use a relative path in java code

Comment: There is some missing piece here. In `script2`, the Java process is launched with the jar `target/dataMigration-...`, implying cwd is 'javafolder`,  but the FNF exception indicate cwd is not javafolder. Can you share CLASSPATH env var and pwd when launching the script1 ? Also, how is the file being opened ?